# How to copy a picture from a web page to a usb drive

Tags: 15.04, paths

I have a USB drive plugged in and can read files I made in Windows, but I don't know how to save a picture from a web page to the USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click the image on web
- Select **Save image as …**
- Select your USB drive
- Click **Save** button

Answer (score 1):

- Open the web page and right click on the picture
- Save the picture
- Open your `Download` folder (the standard folder for that) in Nautilus, the folder is shown in the pane on the right hand side
- Plugin your USB drive, the drive is shown in the pane on the right hand side
- Move the image from the `Download` folder to your USB drive